# Distribute files to a large amount of servers

Tags: linux, distributions, bittorrent

I'm looking for a way to distribute large files to my servers, the same files need to be at all the target servers...

The files are in sizes of 30-600Gb.

Problem: I mount my NFS share source on the targets and start copy at the same time.

At my source server I can see that the disk utilization is high because of intense IO (I guess it's because it need to read the same files over and over) and also network utilization is near it's tops.

I tried UDP broadcast but it didn't worked because of my hosting environment doesn't allow this....

I heard about murder but I didn't found anyone that have actually working with it (except Twitter :) ).

My questions are:

1. Does anyone have any experience with this application (murder, or any other torrent "sync"-like)?
2. Is there any other option to copy the same files to my servers in a short time as possible (I can copy the files to each of the target servers separately, this will not bring my source server to his knees but it will take lot's of time)?

Any ideas will be appreciated

Thanks,

Gili

Comment: What type of files, what frequency, how many times, always or not the same files. Please do not answer in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), with the nodes connected in a tree topology?

Comment: rsync command is easy way to copying big size files.I used rsync to copy 1 TB of files between server and USB external hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas come to mind.

If this is something you do often and with cadence it may be worthwhile to setup an rsync server and configure a cron job on your clients to pull the file from rsync.

If this is done infrequently and on an as-needed basis you can still use rsync manually.  I frequently use ansible for this sort of thing as well, but ansible wants a list of hosts it's allowed to interact with (inventory) and works best if you have ssh keys setup.  Your ansible ad-hoc command would look like

```
ansible <target hosts> -m copy -a "src=<your file> dest=<location of file on destination host>"
```

TBH I'm not sure either of these options will multicast the file (sounds like that's what you're looking for), but you may still see some performance gains elsewhere.

Comment: The thing is, when I'm copping my data to all the servers, every server use a part of the network bandwidth of the source server... This is strangle  my source server. I had in mind to try some distributed FS, or use the same mechanism like torrent are using, So I can distribute my data more efficient...

Comment: Using ansible you can limit the number of transfers that run at any one time by limiting worker threads.  However, if you want a more optimal solution you need to provide more information.  It would be helpful if you included in your original question the size of the data and the frequency at which it needs to be copied.  Including these details will be essential to getting an answer that best fits your needs.